# Why do worksheets spontaneously resize

Tags: ms-office

Excel for Mac 2011; OS 10.13.6 High Sierra; iMac

I keep a number of worksheets open. When I toggle through them using the keyboard shortcut and come back to one I'd previously worked on, it has resized about 25% smaller. It's not really a problem, I'd just like to know why it happens.

Comment: MacOS version?  Specific application?  Do you have a screen capture we can look at to get a clear picture of the issue?

Comment: Sorry; wasn't thinking; Excel for Mac 2011; OS 10.13.6 High Sierra; iMac. I don't see an option for uploading a screen capture.

Comment: To upload a picture, use the Image icon or you can use Ctrl+G

Comment: That’s going to be difficult to replicate. I don’t have any machine currently that can run Office 2011.

Comment: I must be blind. I do not see an "Image icon." Where on the page is it and what does it look like?